# Почему при создании внешнего ключа выдается ошибка: foreign key incorrectly formed?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Код создания таблицы с внешними ключами:

```
CREATE TABLE movies_genres (
        movie_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        genre_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        FOREIGN KEY (movie_id) REFERENCES movies(id),
        FOREIGN KEY (genre_id) REFERENCES genres(id)
    )
```

До этого были созданы две таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE movies (
     title VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
     duration INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
     id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY(id)
)
```

```
CREATE TABLE genres (
     genre VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
     id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY(id)
)
```

**Вопрос:** почему выдается ошибка foreign key incorrectly formed и как это исправить?

Comment: Странно, на на sqlfiddle таблицы отлично создаются. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/edee31  так что причина может быть в какой нибудь опечатке при создании двух предыдущих таблиц в вашей БД

Comment: К запросам претензий нет.  [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fdfca4565755560c3e8b303e7c98d978). Наиболее вероятная причина - отсутствие прав (как в MySQL, так и за его пределами - скажем, в файловой системе) или иных ресурсов.